# DISTINCT on results of a knex.js INNER JOIN

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have two tables, `metadata` and `view_events`. Both `metadata` and `view_events` have `config_id` and `config_type` columns. I'm trying to select all `view_events` for a given user email, distinct by `config_id` and `config_type`, ordered by `timestamp, desc`, and limited to the 10 most recent. The following knex.js code *isn't* working but hopefully expresses what I'm trying to achieve:

```
return dbClient<AuthenticatedUserIndexRow>(METADATA_TABLE_NAME)
    .select([
      `${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.CONFIG_ID}`,
      `${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.CONFIG_TYPE}`,
      `${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.DESCRIPTION}`,
      `${VIEW_EVENTS_TABLE_NAME}.${VIEW_EVENTS_COLUMNS.TIMESTAMP}`,
    ])
    .innerJoin<AuthenticatedUserIndexRow>(VIEW_EVENTS_TABLE_NAME, function innerJoinOnViewEvents() {
      this.on(
        `${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.STORAGE_ID}`,
        '=',
        `${VIEW_EVENTS_TABLE_NAME}.${VIEW_EVENTS_COLUMNS.CONFIG_STORAGE_ID}`,
      )
        .andOn(
          `${VIEW_EVENTS_TABLE_NAME}.${VIEW_EVENTS_COLUMNS.USER_EMAIL}`,
          '=',
          rawSql('?', [authUserEmail]),
        )
        .andOn(`${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.DELETED}`, '=', rawSql('?', [false]));
    })
    .distinct([
      `${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.CONFIG_TYPE}`,
      `${METADATA_TABLE_NAME}.${METADATA_COLUMNS.CONFIG_ID}`,
    ])
    .limit(EVENT_LIMIT)
    .orderBy(VIEW_EVENTS_COLUMNS.TIMESTAMP, 'desc');
```

For example, given the following tables:

```
view_events
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| config_type | config_id |        timestamp         |        email         |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| a           | foo       | 2020-01-23T03:08:14.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
| a           | foo       | 2020-01-23T03:08:14.500Z | jane.doe@gmail.com   |
| a           | foo       | 2020-01-23T03:08:13.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
| a           | bar       | 2020-01-23T03:08:12.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
| a           | foo       | 2020-01-23T03:08:11.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
| b           | foo       | 2020-01-23T03:08:10.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
| a           | baz       | 2020-01-23T03:08:09.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
| a           | foo       | 2020-01-23T03:08:08.618Z | john.smith@gmail.com |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------------+

metadata
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+
| config_type | config_id |        description        |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+
| a           | foo       | Type a config with id foo |
| a           | bar       | Type a config with id bar |
| b           | foo       | Type b config with id foo |
| a           | baz       | Type a config with id baz |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+
```

I am trying to obtain the following output (given an `authUserEmail` of `john.smith@gmail.com`):

```
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+
| config_type | config_id |        description        |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+
| a           | foo       | Type a config with id foo |
| a           | bar       | Type a config with id foo |
| b           | foo       | Type b config with id foo |
| a           | baz       | Type a config with id baz |
+-------------+-----------+---------------------------+
```

I'm not a SQL expert, but am generally aware that the use of `SELECT` and `DISTINCT` together here doesn't work. What's the correct approach?

Comment: Do you mean you only want one row back per config id/type? Maybe provide minimal input/output example just to clarify the requirements?

Comment: Correct. I'll add that to the original question.

Comment: It's sounding to me like you want `groupBy` in which case you need to aggregate the remaining columns in the select list. Possibly just grabbing the latest (max) timestamp would do...

Comment: Not entirely sure that I follow. Does the provided input/output help clarify my question?

Comment: I think so, will have a blast...

Comment: Have added an attempt at solving, below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following roughly work for you? I did using with as so we could grab the 10 most recent configs (`max(timestamp)..group by config`) and then remove the timestamp column in the final projection. Note the final records may not appear in exact timestamp order as you did not want timestamp in your final output, but they will be the 10 most recent. I haven't added the `DELETED` column but imagine you will re-add that based on the code in your question.

```js
knex.with('ordered_items', (qb) =>
          qb.table('metadata')
          .innerJoin('view_events', function() {
              this.on('metadata.config_id', '=', 'view_events.config_id')
                  .andOn('metadata.config_type', '=', 'view_events.config_type')
          })
          .where({'view_events.email': 'john.smith@gmail.com'})
          .select(['metadata.config_type', 'metadata.config_id',
                   'metadata.description'])
          .max('view_events.timestamp', {as: 'max_ts'})
          .groupBy(['metadata.config_id', 'metadata.config_type', 'metadata.description'])
          .orderBy('max_ts', 'desc')
          .limit(10))
    .table('ordered_items')
    .select(['config_type', 'config_id', 'description'])
```

My input and output:

```
sqlite> select * from metadata;
a|foo|Type a config with id foo
a|bar|Type a config with id bar
b|foo|Type b config with id foo
a|baz|Type a config with id baz
sqlite> select * from view_events;
a|foo|2020-01-23T03:08:14.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
a|foo|2020-01-23T03:08:14.500Z|jane.doe@gmail.com
a|foo|2020-01-23T03:08:13.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
a|bar|2020-01-23T03:08:12.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
a|foo|2020-01-23T03:08:11.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
b|foo|2020-01-23T03:08:10.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
a|baz|2020-01-23T03:08:09.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
a|foo|2020-01-23T03:08:08.618Z|john.smith@gmail.com
```

```
[ { config_type: 'a',
    config_id: 'foo',
    description: 'Type a config with id foo' },
  { config_type: 'a',
    config_id: 'bar',
    description: 'Type a config with id bar' },
  { config_type: 'b',
    config_id: 'foo',
    description: 'Type b config with id foo' },
  { config_type: 'a',
    config_id: 'baz',
    description: 'Type a config with id baz' } ]
```

Comment: "with \"ordered_events\" as (select max(\"view_events\".\"timestamp\") from \"metadata\" inner join \"view_events\" on \"metadata\".\"storage_id\" = \"view_events\".\"config_storage_id\" where \"view_events\".\"user\" = $1 and \"metadata\".\"deleted\" = $2 group by \"metadata\".\"config_id\", \"metadata\".\"config_type\", \"metadata\".\"description\" order by \"view_events\".\"timestamp\" desc limit $3) select \"config_id\", \"config_type\", \"description\" from \"ordered_events\" - column \"view_events.timestamp\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: I don't know if it matters or not, but I'm using Postgres whereas your solution looks to be run against sqlite.

Comment: Mm `sqlite3` *is* rather forgiving. I've made an attempt to fix based on the error, fingers crossed it works but if not I can flip over to postgres and fix it there. Let me know.

Comment: That did it! Marking as resolved. Curious though, what about adding the "as" clause fixes the initial error?

Comment: Awesome -- thank you. Not so much the `as` which fixed, as ordering by `max(timestamp)` rather than `timestamp`, the latter is invalid sql but `sqlite3` was letting through. In order to sort by `max(timestamp)`, it seemed easier to add an alias, hence the `as`. Hope this is clear.